# system compiler variables are not overwritten in merged project

Tags: install4j

I have a launcher in a sub-project whose name is dependend on the `${compiler:sys.version}` variable.
The project is merged into a parent project, which is build with a gradle task on command line.

```
task serverSetup(type: com.install4j.gradle.Install4jTask, dependsOn: 'initialize') {
    projectFile = file('server.install4j')
    release = artifactVersion
}
```

Problem is, that the launcher of the sub-project is created with the value set in the sub-projects Application Info and not overridden with the version set by the gradle task.

Am I doing something wrong? The documentation says:

> As a result of flat merging, there are no intermediary artifacts for merged projects. .... In particular, all elements in the final result share the same
>   namespace for compiler and installer variables.

Because of this I expect the sys.version variable to be overriden in the sub-project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a bug, it will be fixed in 7.0.5. Please contact support@ej-technologies.com to get a build where this already fixed.